# Add Attribute to the property dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamicobject

Following Implementation which is creating class and property dynamically:

```
public static class MyTypeBuilder
{
    public static void CreateNewObject()
    {
        var myType = CompileResultType();

    }
    public static Type CompileResultType()
    {
        TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder();
        ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

                        var fields = new List<Field>() { 
            new Field("EmployeeID", typeof(int)),
            new Field("EmployeeName", typeof(string)),
            new Field("Designation", typeof(string)) 
        };

        // NOTE: assuming your list contains Field objects with fields FieldName(string) and FieldType(Type)
                        foreach (var field in fields)
            CreateProperty(tb, field.FieldName, field.FieldType);

        Type objectType = tb.CreateType();
        return objectType;
    }

    private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
    {
        var typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
        var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
        TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature
                            , TypeAttributes.Public |
                            TypeAttributes.Class |
                            TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                            TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                            TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                            TypeAttributes.AutoLayout
                            , null);
        return tb;
    }

    private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
        MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
            tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
              MethodAttributes.Public |
              MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
              MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
              null, new[] { propertyType });

        ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
        Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

        setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
    }
}
```

In same above implementation i want to add attribute for the property 
Example

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
   [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
   private class myDyanmicType
   {   
       [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
       public int EmployeeID;     
       [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
       public String EmployeeName;
       [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
       public String Designation;          

   }
```

so i want to add attribute to the property like

`[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]`

how i will achieve this with my code of creating the dynamic class and property

Please help.

Comment: No, you can't do that unless the class was designed for that. *Why* are you trying to do that? Can you use a different class which refers to an instance of the existing class? It's hard to help you without more context.

Comment: if NO the is it possible to create entire class dynamically with dynamic property and attribute for the property. now i am able to create the class and property dynamically with above code updated the main question description please check.

Comment: Yes, you can create classes dynamically, or use ExpandoObject... but that's *very* different from saying "I've already got a class, and I want to add properties dynamically to that." It's still not clear what you're really trying to achieve, or why you think that's best done in this way.

Comment: _already having class is the one approach i was trying_ . if this not able achieve easily then **i will create the entire class dynamically with dynamic property which i have already achieve with the above code** , but now only one thing i am not able to understand how i will add the attribute dynamically to those properties which i am creating with above code.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite the question completely to be *very* clear about what you're trying to do then. It's still really unclear to me at the moment.

Comment: please check i have changed my question .

Comment: Okay, so have you *tried* anything in terms of applying the attribute? `PropertyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute` would seem the obvious way forward...

Answer (score 0):

Just a simpler and faster approach: Write your appreciated code to a string, then compile it at runtime, and you will get everything ready!

```
string src = "[DelimitedRecord(\",\")] [IgnoreEmptyLines()] private class ...";
var compParms = new CompilerParameters
            {
                GenerateExecutable = false,
                GenerateInMemory = true
            };
var csProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerResults compilerResults = csProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compParms, src);
var a = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly; // here you go
```